# Pickle File Import Error

Tags: python, pickle, importerror

I have been trying to load a Python pickle file using the following Python function:

```
import os 
import cPickle as pickle

def load_var(var_name):
    fid = open(var_name + '.pkl', 'rb')
    data = pickle.load(fid)
    fid.close()
    return data
```

but I keep on running into the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named sysid_functions
```

It's complaining about a module named sysid that is called in the pickle.py file. If I import pickle instead of (cPickle as pickle), I get the following more detailed error output:

```
 File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1378, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1090, in load_global
    klass = self.find_class(module, name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1124, in find_class
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named sysid_functions
```

Does anybody have any idea what might be causing the error?

Comment: Do you have the corresponding write to the pickle file?

Comment: What do you mean the corresponding write? I was given a set of .pkl files, and I am trying to read those files using the above method.

Comment: That wasn't clear in your post. I thought maybe you wrote out the pkl files too. I guess that would be a good first step, does it work with a pickle file you create?

Comment: Yup, sorry! It is working for a pickle file that I manually write.

Answer (score 1):

Pickle files don't actually store class or module definitions.  They only store attribute values.  The benefit to this is that you can pickle out an object, update the class definition in your source code, then read in the pickled data and it will use the new class definition instead of having two different versions of the same class.

The downside is that pickle files aren't really transferrable between different python environments (and can't reliably even be transferred across different python files or modules).  When it comes to loading a class or object, the pickle file uses the same import structure/namespace that was present when the pickle was created.  That means that pickle files created from the same module that defines a class can only be reloaded in that same module (unless you manually import that class into your global namespace).

For all we know `sysid_functions` was a sub-module of some other package that you don't have installed.  Even if you did have it installed, you would likely only be able to load the pickle file if you managed set up your module `globals()` the same way that the module that created the pickle file was set up.

Comment: Does this issue go away if you use `json` or `yaml`?

Comment: @busfault No. The problem isn't the serialization format.  The problem is trying to serialize a complex datatype.  In fact, json or yaml only support serializing the basic datatypes.  Those libraries won't even try to serialize a custom class unless you provide a custom Encoder/Decoder.